# How to arrange SQL query result with column group?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, mysqli

```
SELECT Product_type FROM product INNER JOIN product Product_type.typeid = product.pid
I have this sql query result list. This is exactly what i need.

--------------------------
Product_type  | Product
--------------------------
ProductType 1 | Poduct A
ProductType 1 | Poduct B
ProductType 1 | Poduct C
ProductType 1 | Poduct D
ProductType 2 | Poduct E
ProductType 2 | Poduct F
ProductType 2 | Poduct G
--------------------------
```

Now, my question is how to get list of product based on product type. Is there any way to get such result with sql query?

I need frontend output as bellow:

```
ProductType 1
    | Product A
    | Product B
    | Product C
    | Product D
ProductType 2
    | Product E
    | Product F
    | Product G
```

Or how can i store result in multi-dimational array based on product_type. Can anyone help.

Big Thanks an advance!

Comment: It is kind a tree structure, not a table structure.

Comment: @ShaunakShukla, I just wanted all product arranged with project_type listing purpose.

Comment: I have solution with SQL query, I need one concern, from where do you get Product column?

Comment: I have two table with various field product_type and product it self.  I need only two column info as given above

Comment: ok, product_type and product are two tables, and product table has reference id of product_type, on which you are joining the table, right?

Comment: Exactly.. first table has given above it the result of join query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153727/discussion-between-ghanshyam-bhava-and-shaunak-shukla).

Comment: I doubt that there's an introductory text on PHP and MySQL that would fail to address this

Comment: @Strawberry, I doubt that you have given me negative for my answer, may I know why I get negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution from our discussion, it may help you.

Your query would be like below :

```
SELECT product_type.product_type, GROUP_CONCAT(products.product) AS pros FROM product_type LEFT JOIN products ON product_type.id = products.product_type_id GROUP BY product_type.id
```

This will give you output as below array:

```
$result_arr = array(
                array(  'product_type'=>'ProductType 1',
                        'pros'=>'product A, product B, product C'),
                array(  'product_type'=>'ProductType 2',
                        'pros'=>'product D, product E, product F')
                );
```

Then you can manipulate that output as below :

```
foreach($result_arr as $key=>$val){
    echo "<b>".$val['product_type']."</b><br/>";
    $products = explode(',',$val['pros']);
    foreach($products as $product){
        echo $product."</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can Anybody explain, who gave me negative? and why?

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the result and loop through it to get the desired result

```
$sql = "SELECT Product_type FROM product INNER JOIN product Product_type.typeid = product.pid";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          $newarray[$row['product_type']][] = $row['product']; 

        }




 print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
SELECT Product_type FROM product INNER JOIN product Product_type.typeid = product.pid GROUP BY Product_type;
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Thank for answer, I tried before GROUP BY not works for me

Comment: you need to try GROUP BY if you are operating on group_by then it is wrong.https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby refer this if it helps :)

Comment: In my view, this is not a sensible solution

Answer (score 1):

> Now, my question is how to get list of product based on product type.
>   Is there any way to get such result with sql query?
>   Or how can i store result in multi-dimational array based on product_type. Can anyone help.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "mydb");
$query = "put your query string here";

$output = array();

// From your sql_query result list
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) 
{

   /* fetch object array */
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
         if(isset( $output[ $row['product_type'] ] ))
         {
                 $output[ $row['product_type'] ][] = $row['product'];
                 continue;
         }
         $output[ $row['product_type'] ] = array( $row['product']  );
   }
         print_r( $output ); // Here is your multi-dimational array
}
```

Comment: I didn't get that why you fetch row? I tried this its shows undefined index product_type and product.

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava: Sorry I modified now

Answer (score 0):

you fetch the results of this query in `$row` and then,

```
$product_type1 = array();
$product_type2 = array();
while ($row) {
    if($row['Product_type'] == '1') {
        array_push($product_type1, $row['Product']);
    }
    else if($row['Product_type'] == '2') {
        array_push($product_type2, $row['Product']);
    }
}
```

and now use this arrays to display the values in front end.

Comment: This is rather impractical